How to \AddToHook{begindocument}{<code>}, but avoid the log of font initialisation in l3build testing?
Suppose I have the following .lvt:
\documentclass{article}
\input{regression-test}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{abcd}

\START
% \OMIT% Doesn't work as expected
\begin{document}
% \TIMO% Doesn't work as expected
\end{document}

and, I run it with a simple build.lua like:
module     = "duck"

It generates a .tlg which I will breakdown in two parts. The first part includes the log I want. It is as follows:
This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.
Don't change this file in any respect.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l. ...\begin{document}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

After this, it adds this:
(../l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def ....-..-.. L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count...
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box...
)
No file test.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line ....
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line ....
[1
] (test.aux)

I don't know if omitting the second part is a good idea from a testing perspective, but intuitively it doesn't give any logical information for testing small macros which I intend to test. Thus I am willing to avoid (or better, \OMIT it :P). In the MWE, when I say, \OMIT doesn't work as expected, I mean it eats up the part of the log I want to have too when added before \begin{document}. @Skillmon's answer suggests a workaround which works for the specific MWE:
% Courtesy: Jonathan P. Spratte
% https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=8031#a7642
\documentclass{article}
\input{regression-test}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{abcd\OMIT}

\START
\begin{document}
\TIMO
\end{document}

but extending it to a real situation is difficult, because I have some code in the .cls I am writing and that is not included in a user-level macro. I insert it /before begindocument. In the source, I of course can't have \OMIT. So is there any way I can omit this initialisation? Is there any way I can break the \begin{document} in parts and only \OMIT the concerned part? Is this a wise idea considering a test-suit of a standard public release?

can't you add the \OMIT into the hook in the test file? presumably, you have a labelled hook for the code you add in the class file, so you could add it into that hook. or, if you need it in a different place, you could just have an empty hook in the class file.

or you could just use the ordering rules for hooks in the test file to make sure the test hook is executed after the class hook? but you should give an example which does show what you want to do. one which doesn't demonstrate the problem doesn't make it easy to suggest anything sensible. should /before begindocument be begindocument/before?

Thanks, it worked!! I will update with an answer.

@cfr the workaround is perfect, can you also comment on whether this is a good idea or not?

I don't really understand the question, can't you just put \START after \begin{document} ?

@DavidCarlisle, I can't. The reason is the code that is executed before \begin{document} is important. But the initialization related to fonts is not. The example seen in the answers can give you an idea.

@DavidCarlisle do label choices matter in a test file? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724967/how-to-addtohookbegindocumentcode-but-avoid-the-log-of-font-initialisati/724970?noredirect=1#comment1804685_724970) I'd assume not.

If I understand the question,  no its just a name @cfr

Thanks @DavidCarlisle.

@DavidCarlisle they're all just names ... but thanks.

What I had in mind was something more like this:
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}[test]% label the code you put in hooks (or read the docs to figure out which label gets used by default)
% \AddToHook{begindocument/before}[.]% this assigns the current default label, which is the package or class name inside a package or class and this is the right label to use
{%
  abcd%
}

\documentclass{test}
\input{regression-test}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}[test]{\OMIT}
\START
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}

If you are not sure what exactly is going on in the chunk of code test e.g. whether \OMIT might end up before something you want the output from, it would be better to order them explicitly. For example, you can say something like
\documentclass{test}
\input{regression-test}
% in a document, everything gets added to top-level by default
% I find it clearer to explicitly label in this case so I get a meaningful label and can be sure I'm looking at the right chunk
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}[buildtest]{\OMIT}
% you need to be explicit here
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument/before}{test}{before}{buildtest}
\START
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}


Thanks! Didn't know about labels. Will read more about them. The second method looks better to me, because giving a tag to the hook in the class file is not helpful for general users is what I guess (or, is it? I am not sure). Also, from your wording, it seems the second method is safer too. So I will follow that. Thanks in any case :)

@Niranjan as I understand it, everything you put in a hook gets a label. so if you are using the begindocument/before hook in the class, that code chunk will get a default label if you don't supply one. it can be useful to more experienced users of your package. for example, somebody might want to make sure that something happens before or after the code your class adds. or they might want to change it. (hard to know what makes sense without knowing what code the class adds, obviously.) also helpful for debugging because you can show what is in a hook etc.

thanks for the suggestion, if I understand correctly, you suggest creating a label for the hook and any arbitrary key should work as the label, right? I will add it exactly like I see it in your code.

@Niranjan if this is in a class or package you should use the class or package name. or you can just use a dot . and latex will add the appropriate label. but in the test file I don't think it matters. if it later conflicts with something, you can change it. I'd still go for something with the package or class name in it, but it's not like code which might get used in a real document. you could ask David for a more informed answer. You could also just use . for the test file and latex will label it as top-level.

@Niranjan I've added a couple of comments to the code. but all I've really done is read some of the docs, so take what I say for what it isn't worth.

Thanks again for the prompt response, I was contemplating using the class name itself. I will have a look at the docs too :)

@Niranjan that is definitely the right name in the class file. the idea is this will help with the tangled conflicts you get when packages all try to throw stuff into \AtBeginDocument{}. every chunk of code gets a label and class/pkg code should be in chunks named that way. you can use e.g. <my class name> / first and <my class name> / second if you need to and then tell latex the first should get executed before the second. I suspect in a test file it doesn't matter, but, if it does, I don't know why or what it should be.

@cfr's comments worked for me.
The following .lvt:
\documentclass{test}
\input{regression-test}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\OMIT}
\START
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}

with the following .cls:
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  abcd%
}

produces the .tlg I want:
This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.
Don't change this file in any respect.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l. ...\begin{document}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

We just added another \AddToHook to our .lvt.

but what happens if the code in the test file gets executed before the code from the class? I suppose for testing purposes, everything is controlled, but it still seems safer to me to use labels and ordering.
